# Questions about locally Euclidean

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

Here is the definition of locally euclidean I was given:
A topological space $(X,τ)$ is said to be locally euclidean if there exists a positive integer n such that each point $x∈X$ has an open neighbourhood homeomorphic to an open ball about 0 in R^n with the euclidean metric. A Hausdorff locally euclidean space is said to be a topological manifold.

This is the first time I learned what locally euclidean means so I am wondering if I am on the right track with these questions below

(i)Prove that every non-trivial interval $(a,b)$, $a,b ∈ \Bbb{R}$, is locally euclidean.

Every open neighbourhood of elements of open intervals are just open intervals which are homeomorphic to any open interval in $\Bbb{R}$. So they are all homeomorphic to $(0-e,0+e)$.

(ii)  Let $S^1$ be the subspace of $\Bbb{R}^2$ consisting of all $x∈\Bbb{R}^2$ such that $d(x,0) = 1$, where $d$ is the Euclidean metric. Show that the space $S^1$ is locally Euclidean.

Every neighborhood of point of $S^1$ are just connected segment of the circle without the endpoints and we are given that these are homeomorphic to open intervals in $\Bbb{R}$ so they must be homeomorphic to $(0-e, 0+e)$.

(iii) Find an example of a locally Euclidean space which is not a topological manifold?

I am currently stuck on this one. This is the first time I learned what a topological manifold is and it seems like a lot of locally Euclidean space are Hausdorff.

Answer (score 1):

$(i)$ is trivial, we take $n=1$ and note that $X$ itself is homeomorphic to $(-1,1)$, say.

For $(ii)$ we note that $\phi(x)=e^{2i\pi(t + \phi_0)}$ is a homeomorphism between $(-1,1)$ and an open neighbourhood of (ana arbitrary point, chose $\phi_0$ as you please) $e^{2\pi i\phi_0}$ in $S^1$ (seen for convenience as the unit circle in $\Bbb C$).

Problem $(iii)$ is one you know or don't. The standard example is to take a Hausdorff space like $\Bbb R$ and double one of its points, so that we cannot separate it from its "twin". It's called [the line with two origins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Hausdorff_manifold#Line_with_two_origins), usually. It shows that just being **locally** Euclidean (so locally Hausdorff too) doesn't mean it's Hausdorff **globally**.

Answer (score 0):

To help with the question you are stuck on consider:

The quotient space of the disjoint union of two copies of $R$, via the identification of $x$ in the first copy with $x$ in the second copy, for $x \neq 0$. This is known as the line with two origins.